# Homekit application gets signal SIGABRT error

Tags: ios, xcode, homekit

I am new to Apple HomeKit and iOS development, I have a UITableViewController which tries to manage an instance of HMHomeManager, but every time after the HMHomeManager instance is initialised, the program crashed with signal: SIGABRT.

the interface:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Homekit/HomeKit.h>

@interface ItemListTableViewController : UITableViewController <HMHomeManagerDelegate>

@property HMHomeManager* homeManager;

@end
```

Then I have the implementation:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.homeManager = [[HMHomeManager alloc] init];
    self.homeManager.delegate = self;
}
```

And when this view is shown, the program crashes with SIGABRT:

```
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:

0x108277efc <+0>:  movl   $0x2000148, %eax          ; imm = 0x2000148 
0x108277f01 <+5>:  movq   %rcx, %r10
0x108277f04 <+8>:  syscall 
->  0x108277f06 <+10>: jae    0x108277f10               ; <+20>
0x108277f08 <+12>: movq   %rax, %rdi
0x108277f0b <+15>: jmp    0x1082727cd               ; cerror_nocancel
0x108277f10 <+20>: retq   
0x108277f11 <+21>: nop    
0x108277f12 <+22>: nop    
0x108277f13 <+23>: nop
```

Great thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you turned exception breakpoints on?

Comment: Hi, I figured it out, it's because I haven't set info.plist with homekit privacy enabled.. thanks! and btw, how to turn exception breakpoints on? I don't know if I did it wrong, but it seems it's not helping.

Comment: Press the plus sign at the bottom of the _Breakpint Navigator_, and choose _Exception Breakpoint..._. The debugger will then stop when an exception is thrown. But according to your description this seems not to help in this case.

Comment: I've done that, it will certainly help me when I am continuing my development work. thanks!